# Potential JavaScript/php query

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'd like to think I'm fluent in html and css and I'm planning on broadening my horizons in the world of web development. Is there a way to create a set template for a div with a class using basic html/css or even javascript/php?

For example any div tag that is created with the class "test" will have preset elements as shown below.

```
<div class="test"> 
 <h1></h1><br />
 <p></p>
</div>
```

Updated to javascript..

Using the suggested Jquery code it hasn't responded correctly.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>$(".test").html("<h1>TEST</h1><br /><p>TEST</p>");</script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="test"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I believe you mean Java**Script**. Java isn't often used on the web.

Comment: If you use a JavaScript library, jQuery, it is as simple as: `$("#1").html("<h1></h1><br /><p></p>");`

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Actually, he could be talking about Java. PHP and Java are essentially equal in functionality, but not equally popular.

Comment: Java is absolutely used on the web as jsp pages. And you could do something like that with page fragments.

Comment: You probably want to change your class name, nathzOO, only an integer or even an integer as first character usually gives unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Thats obvious. JavaScript is popular because it is the ONLY language the browsers generally support. Java is a **backend** language, just like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in HTML with a special tag called `<script>`. `<script>` basically tells the browser not to display the text, to instead run it as **JavaScript**. If you want to learn more about JavaScript Syntax, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax) may help. You can use an open source library called [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to make your JavaScript code shorter. To use jQuery, you need to include

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your HTML document (preferably in `<head>`). To do what you asked, you just need to use jQuery's `$` (in another `<script>`):

```
$(".test").html("<h1></h1><br />
                 <p></p>");
```

What this does is it selects (`$`) all elements class (`.`) test, and sets their internal HTML (the HTML inside of them) to your specified code. Your head should now look like:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test"> </div>
    <script>
        $(".test").html("<h1></h1><br /><p></p>");
    </script>
</body>
```

The script must go second so the `<div>` is there to modify.

Comment: I've applied your script to a test.html page and for some reason i can't get it to work. I have edited the above with the example in place.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do. "Templates" are not generally a JS or PHP thing, but you can use libraries and such to use these.

One widely used PHP library is [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), which is, as it says, a "Template Engine". Similar things can be found for JS, such as [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). I suggest doing some looking around and see what works best for you.